# How to use sheet-js git library in Google AppScript?

Tags: javascript, git, github, google-apps-script, sheetjs

I am trying to convert a 2d array in excel file using google appscript. For that I am using sheet-js library.. but it is showing me error.

[image: NOT A FUNCTION ERROR]

I am using xlsx.min file as xlsx.full.min is causing another error.

[image: JSZIPSYNC ERRRR]

After using jszip.js still it is not resolving my issue.

Could you please suggest the appropriate way to use this?

Comment: Try to check first from the [documentation of Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts) if you are missing something. It's really hard to tell what's causing your error since everyone has no view of your code, but do visit the [Apps Script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/) as well. From there you will get [samples from Github](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-samples) on how to implement operations in Sheets using Apps Script (if I'm not mistaken you are talking about google sheets not ms excel).

Comment: no actually i am talking about ms excel as google sheets has limitations of 10million cells